# Neo4j - Cypher vs Scala-Neo4j API

Tags: scala, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Am new to both Scala and Neo4j. I wanted to use Neo4j embedded in my Scala Project. Which is the better way of using it among Cypher queries and Scala-Neo4j API?

Answer (score 1):

I would say Cypher is the easiest, best documented and declarative way to interact with Neo4j. I would switch to the scala/java API only for 2 reasons:

- Missing functionality like imperative traversals (if ever necessary)
- Performance, which currently still is better in some cases with the embedded API until Cypher is based on a new high-performance Java API

Comment: Could you please tell how to write a Cypher query in Scala using Scala-Neo4j wrapper?